# Plugin cannot be null Error - Spigot Coding

Tags: java, maven, jar, minecraft

I have the error 'Plugin cannot be null' occuring while reloading my Plugin. Actually i tried to solve this 'Bug' for myself, but I think that didn't worked... Hopefully you can help me...

Here are some relevant things:

**The Error-Message**:

```
Could not load 'plugins/OwnChallenges-1.0.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin cannot be null
...
at com.fabo0814.ownchallenges.utils.Utils.delayIt(Utils.java:9) ~[?:?]
```

**Main.class**:

```
    // ... Some stuff ...

    public static Main main;
    PluginManager pm = Bukkit.getPluginManager();
    Position pos = new Position();

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {

        main = this;
        SQL.connect();

        listeners();
        commands();
        tab();

        new Config();
        new RanksConfig();

        doWorldStuff();

    }

    // ... Some Stuff ...
```

**Utils.class**:

```
    // ... Some Stuff ...
    
    public static void delayIt(Runnable run, int delay) {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Main.getPlugin(Main.class), run, delay);
    }

    // ... Some Stuff ...
```

Thanks for any help :D

**EDIT**: If i reload the plugin after i started the server, it functions somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `Main.getPlugin(Main.class)` try using `JavaPlugin.getPlugin(Main.class)`. Also, why do you create an Instance of your `Main` class? You dont need singletons in Bukkit plugins (in fact it isnt a real singleton, because you cant set the access of your constructor to private). Also, try naming your Main class of a plugin as the name of your plugin, example: Your plugins name is AchievementsX, then name your main class AchievementsX, with this naming you can easily implement your plugin into other plugins.

Comment: according to your edit, do you use some external plugins in your onEnable method calls? Please send the console output when starting your server. Are there any errors?

Comment: Well thanks for your help. I just created an Variable in Utils which is used now:

`public void onEnable() {Utils.plugin = this;}`

This actually solved the problem.